# Programmatically trigger scroll in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a fairly contrived example where you can scroll on a blue div, and an event listener will take the event and dispatch a clone of it to another div. I want this to scroll the other div.

This works just fine in chrome (Version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit)) with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqox7vfw/).

```
fake.addEventListener('mousescroll', function(e) {
  var clonedEvent = new e.constructor(e.type, e);
  container.dispatchEvent(clonedEvent);
});
```

However just using the Firefox event `DOMMouseScroll` does not work. It throws an error `TypeError: Illegal constructor.`

It also doesn't work if I manually create a new event.
Firefox version 37.0.2.

```
var clonedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
clonedEvent.initMouseEvent( ... /* data from e */);
```

I have been able to capture the event and set `scrollTop` based on the delta in the event, but this does not use the same animated scroll that happens if you manually scroll on the scroll-able div.

How can I trigger the native scroll behavior of a div through JavaScript? I do not want to use jQuery scroll.